# measuring android user installs google analytics v4

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to use the google analytics v4 to measure user installs, followed the tutorial and added:

1)added the google play services to the project

2) added the service and receiver

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" /> 
  <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true">   
      <intent-filter> 
          <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />   
      </intent-filter> 
  </receiver>
```

3)added the permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I am sending the event:

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.app.test/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

but no matter what I do I get:

"No campagin data found"

what am I missing? do I need to Initialize Trackers if all I want to do is to measure the installs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was working fine, the "No campaign data found" output came from other installed apps, which caused the confusion.

Once I enabled the logging

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
```

the "campaign found" message showed.